# How to transfer data between components in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to transfer data form my main vue js to a vue component. My project is built with laravel. I've app.js that mainly work for vue. And also have other components. I would like to transfer data between them.
Please check my code.

This is my **app.js**

```
require('./bootstrap');
import Vue from "vue";
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'

Vue.use(VueResource);
Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = $('input[name="csrf-token"]').attr('value');

Vue.component('google-map', require('./components/GoogleMap.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        lat: 0,
        lng: 0,
        center: { lat: 45.508, lng: -73.587 },
    },
    created(){
        this.lat = 34.20;
        this.lng = 100.36; 
        this.setCenter();
    },
    methods: {
        setCenter(){
            this.center.lat = parseFloat(this.lat);
            this.center.lng = parseFloat(this.lng);
        }
    }
});
```

This is my **GoogleMap.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "GoogleMap",
  data() {
    return {
      center: { lat: 45.508, lng: -73.587 },
    };
  },

  mounted() {
    this.centerFun();
  },

  methods: {
    centerFun(){
        console.log(this.center);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

This is my **map.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Map</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">

        <label>Lat</label><input type="text" name="" v-model="lat" @keyup="testFun">
        <label>Lng</label><input type="text" name="" v-model="lng" @keyup="testFun">

        <google-map></google-map>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see there are two "center" var.
Can I bind those to a single one? Or what can I do?
If I've multiple components, how can I transfer data form app.js to those components or those components to app.js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update **GoogleMap.vue** to this:

```
<template>
  <div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "GoogleMap",
  props: ['center'],
  data() {
    return {
      // center: { lat: 45.508, lng: -73.587 },
    };
  },

  mounted() {
    // this.centerFun();
  },

  methods: {
    //centerFun(){
    //    console.log(this.center);
    //}
  }
};
</script>
```

...so that it can accept the `center` prop from the parent component. And then send center from your parent component to googlemap component like this:

```
<google-map :center="center"></google-map>
```

As @AlxTheRed mentioned, more info about how props work can be found at:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

Comment: More information on props in Vue can be found here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass values from parent component to child component via props.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the variables you want from the parent component as **props** in child component.

In parent component, where you are including your child component:

```
<child-comp var1="abc" :var2="xyz"></child-comp>
```

In child component's instance, declare these as props:

```
props: ['var1','var2'],
```

Now, in child component, you can directly access them as:

```
this.var1
```

Read more here:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

Comment: Does this pass by reference? If you update the value in one component does it work back up to the parent and in to other components which have been given that variable?

Comment: You should avoid doing this. If you mutate a prop in child component, it will be changed back when parent component reloads or change the prop value.

Comment: All props form a one-way-down binding between the child property and the parent one: when the parent property updates, it will flow down to the child, but not the other way around. Also, objects and arrays in JavaScript are passed by reference, so if the prop is an array or object, mutating the object or array itself inside the child component will affect parent state.  https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

Answer (score 0):

If your structure contains many dependencies, I suggest you to use [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/).